# My ModelForm isn't getting auto-populated

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

In the update template my form isnt getting prepopulated however the functionality of updating is working fine. the form stays empty when i am trying to parse an instance of a specific ID

My view.py :

```
def update_component(request, pk):
    component = Component.objects.all()
    component_id = Component.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = ComponentModelForm(instance=component_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ComponentModelForm(request.POST, instance=component_id)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
    context = {
        'components': component,
        'form': ComponentModelForm(),
        'component_id':component_id,
    }        
    return render(request, 'update_component.html', context)
```

The form in template :

```
 <div>
         {% load widget_tweaks %}
         <form class="component-form-flex" method='POST' action=''>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div style="width:50%;" >
               <br>
               <span class="component-label-text">Name</span>

               {% render_field form.name class="component-form"  %}

               <span class="component-label-text">Manufacturer</span>
               {% render_field form.manufacturer class="component-form"   %}

               <span class="component-label-text">Model</span>
               {% render_field form.model class="component-form"   %}

               <span class="component-label-text">Serial Number</span>
               {% render_field form.serial_number class="component-form"  %}

               <span class="component-label-text">Price</span>
               {% render_field form.price class="component-form"  %}

               <span class="component-label-text">Note</span>
               {% render_field form.note class="component-form"  %}

               {% render_field form.parent class="component-form"  %}

               <input type="submit" class="form-submit-button" value='Update Component' />
            </div>
            <div>
               <img class="maintenance-nav-list-img" src="{{ component_id.image.url }}" />
               {% render_field form.image %}
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
```

urls.py :

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
appname = 'maintenance'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index , name='maintenance'),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', views.update_component , name='update_component'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a typo, instead of

```py
   context = {
        'components': component,
        'form': ComponentModelForm(),
        'component_id':component_id,
    }
```

it should be

```py
   context = {
        'components': component,
        'form': form,  # <--- HERE !!!!
        'component_id':component_id,
    }
```

Comment: Thanks plenty, you rock